# A sum is in $\mathbb Z$ implies its last term is also an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, integers

*While working with a larger proof, I wanted to prove the following result which I hope is true.*

---

**The question.**

Let $(e_k)$ be a sequence which takes it values in $\{1,2\}$.

Let $\gamma,\delta\in\{0,\ldots,7^n\}$ such that $(\gamma,\delta)\notin\{(0,0),(0,7^n),(7^n,0),(7^n,7^n)\}$.

> Assuming $$K=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\gamma e_k+\delta}{7^k}\in\mathbb Z,$$ does this imply $$\frac{\gamma e_n+\delta}{7^n}\in\mathbb Z\qquad ?$$

---

**What I tried.**

- I have showed that without loss of generality, we can assume $\gcd(7,\gamma)=\gcd(7,\delta)=1$.
- We can also assume that $7\mid \gamma e_n+\delta$ or it is straightforward.
- Regarding Dietrich Burde's comment, if $\gamma=0$, then $\delta\ne 7^n$, so if we observe the $7$-adic development of $K$, it as a digit $<1$, which is absurd.

*Any hints or leads would be much appreciated.*

Comment: Are you letting $n\rightarrow \infty$?  Or do we have $n\leq N < \infty$?

Comment: @postmortes The result must be shown for all $n\geqslant N$.

Comment: What about $\gamma=0$ ? At least we cannot assume that $gcd(\gamma,7)=1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde If $\gamma=0$, it will be easy to prove that the condition $\sum_k \in\mathbb Z$ will not be fulfilled.

Comment: Then you could add the proof to your post for the case $\gamma=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Done.

Comment: If $K(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\gamma e_k+\delta}{7^k}\in\mathbb Z,$ implies $\frac{\gamma e_n+\delta}{7^n}\in\mathbb Z$ then $K(n-1)=K(n)-\frac{\gamma e_n+\delta}{7^n} \in \mathbb Z$ so finally all $K(k) \in \mathbb Z $ and all $\frac{\gamma e_k+\delta}{7^k} \in \mathbb Z$, $k=0,\ldots,n$ or does this hold only for a certain $n$?

Comment: If only holds for a certain $n$ (as large as you want though), because $\gamma$ and $\delta$ depends on $n$...

Answer (score 1):

I found a counter-example:

$$(7^2-1)+8+\frac{2(7^2-1)+8}7+\frac{(7^2-1)+8}{7^2}\in\mathbb Z$$

but

$$\frac{(7^2-1)+8}{7^2}=1+\frac{1}{7}\notin\mathbb Z.$$